# child process spawn output file and directory in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, child-process, spawn, ytdl

I am using ffmpeg with child process to merge audio and video, but when i am trying to download the file, it is downloading in the same folder, but i want it to download it in the public folder.

following is my code for the child process spawn.

```
// Start the ffmpeg child process
const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
    // Remove ffmpeg's console spamming
    '-loglevel', '8', '-hide_banner',
    // Redirect/Enable progress messages
    '-progress', 'pipe:3',
    // Set inputs
    '-i', 'pipe:4',
    '-i', 'pipe:5',
    // Map audio & video from streams
    '-map', '0:a',
    '-map', '1:v',
    // Keep encoding
    '-c:v', 'copy',
    // Define output file
    'title.mp4',
], {
    windowsHide: true,
    stdio: [
        /* Standard: stdin, stdout, stderr */
        'inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit',
        /* Custom: pipe:3, pipe:4, pipe:5 */
        'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
    ],
});
```

Comment: `// Define output file`, perhaps try changing the path, e.g './public/title.mp4',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `cwd` option. It will set the path your child process execute its code. For instance if you liked to run your process at the root of your fs, you would do that:

```
............
], {
    cwd: '/',
    windowsHide: true,
    stdio: [
        /* Standard: stdin, stdout, stderr */
        'inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit',
        /* Custom: pipe:3, pipe:4, pipe:5 */
        'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
    ],
});
```

so set the path to your public folder and then it should be download there.

Comment: can you please help me to change the name of the output file, i am trying to change it with a string assigned to a variable and it gives an error and close the process.

I am doing like `${fileName}.mp4`

Comment: that should work for instance `const dd = console.log('archchchchch'); const x = spawn(process.execPath, ['-e', \`${dd}\`])`

Comment: i mean for you it may be   ....'-c:v', 'copy',\` ${fileName}.mp4\`], {.....   . Of course the fileName must be declare before

Comment: i have already done like this, but it doesn't work, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Strange, it should work. Have you tryied to set a variable first then pass it, like: `let name = \`${filename}.mp4\`; const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [...,.'-c:v', 'copy',\`${name}\`], { `